# How can I enable request only for user's own endpoint

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

I have a rest-endpoint like this:
/users/{userId}/something

I implemented authentification using oauth2. 
My WebSecurityConfig looks like this:

```
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
    .authorizeRequests()
    .anyRequest().authenticated()
    .and()
    .formLogin()
    .loginPage("/login").permitAll();
}
```

How can I only allow users to access their own endpoint (eg. User with Id 100 can only access `/users/100/something`) without beeing able to see another endpoint (like `/users/200/something`)?

Is this possible?

Comment: This path doesn't make a whole ton of sense in a RESTful context.  The way I read that route, you're *accessing* the user at ID 100 or ID 200 and invoking something about them.  If you wanted to restrict individuals, I'd imagine you want to use groups to restrict certain endpoints to certain groups, but I'm not entirely clear as to what your ultimate objective is here.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I just want to have that each user has only access to his own endpoint (like /users/100/me/ and displaying his own user name for example). 
Are you suggesting that I shouldnt use the userId to provide info about himself and instead do something like this: /users/me?

Comment: On the occasion that I've done something like this, I've generally relied on Spring Security's role framework to extract a user principal when pulling up any kind of privileged information.  Forcing the URL to have the ID in it has a smell about it such that it would be ripe for exploitation - probably not *here*, but it's usually a bad idea to expose user IDs at all anyway.

Comment: Yeah I figured that out too. I decided to change the route to /users/something and taking the id of the authenticated user (from the currently logged in user eg. principal).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many ways to solve this problem, but i have picked out three solutions to apraoch this problem.

#### Custom Security Expression

I would recommend a custom security based annotation approach. This would involve implementing a custom security expression, the related expression handler and the method security configuration. The next appraoch is a little bit simpler if this is too much work for you.

```
public class UserIdentityMethodSecurityExpressionRoot 
    extends SecurityExpressionRoot implements MethodSecurityExpressionOperations {

    public UserIdentityMethodSecurityExpressionRoot(Authentication authentication) {
        super(authentication);
    }

    public boolean userIdentity(Long userId) {
        User user = ((UserPrincipal) this.getPrincipal()).getUser();
        return user.getId() == userId;
    }
}
```

Rest endpoints or service methods can then be annotated with the newly created security expression:

```
@PreAuthorize("userIdentity(#userId)")
@GetMapping
@ResponseBody
public Resource fineOne(@PathVariable Long userId) {
    return resourceService.findOne(id);
}
```

Please note that the `userId` must be provided *somewhere*, either as `@PathVariable` or `@RequestParam`. Spring security will then check if the current user has matches the provided `userId` and returns `403` otherwise.

The full example is available [here](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-create-new-custom-security-expression) and has been adapted in this question for your purposes.

#### SpEL

You can also use SpEL, which is a little bit simpler:

```
@PreAuthorize("#userId == principal.getId()")
@GetMapping
@ResponseBody
public Resource fineOne(@PathVariable Long userId) {
    return resourceService.findOne(id);
}
```

#### Other considerations

You can also do all the work yourself and get to a faster result without defining a custom expression using `SecurityContextHolder`.

```
public static void checkUserIdentity(Long userId) {
    Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
    // user did not provide a token
    if(auth == null) {
        throw new AccessDeniedException(); 
    }      
    UserDetails details = (UserDetails) auth.getPrincipal();
    if(userId != details.getId()) {
        throw new AccessDeniedException(); 
    }
}
```

And using it like:

```
@GetMapping
@ResponseBody
public Resource fineOne(@PathVariable Long userId) {
    SecurityUtils.checkUserIdentity(userId)
    return resourceService.findOne(id);
}
```

Why does this work? The `SecurityContextHolder` will inject the current principal if you have setup Spring security correctly. By default, an authentication is bound to the current thread of execution and will be reset if the request has been processed or encounters an exception.

Comment: That comes quite close to that what I want, I will accept it as answer up so far